# How to print according to string length?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to print a pattern like this:

```
C    C++  Java Java 
Java Java C    C++
```

In above pattern spaces allocated to the largest character

```
char *str1 = "C";
char *str2 = "C++";
char *str3 = "Java";

printf("%s ", str1);printf("%s ", str2);printf("%s ", str3);printf("%s ", str3);
printf("\n%s ", str3);printf("%s ", str3);printf("%s ", str1);printf("%s ", str2);
```

I tried using length of characters and appending length to character pointer but was not successful.

Comment: This is not so clear. What exactly did you *do*? What was the result? Your approach seems sound at first glance (use strlen plus strcat), but the devil is in the details. E.g. who allocated the memory for the extra spaces to go into? Also, as @user3121023 pointed out, are you doing this to format a known output (for which you'd use printf) or are you trying to achieve something further/more complex?

Comment: @lserni i am trying to print character as above. If character have less length then its take space according to longest character and i am printing it using printf

Comment: @JavaTest can you share the printf() statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a method to determine the longest string in any column. Then you can use

```
printf ("%*s ", longestWordInColumn, aColumnEntry[y]);
```

for each column, where `longestWordInColumn` holds this length.

For this to work for *any* list of entries per column, you need to loop a few times over the array of strings, which suggests using arrays.

If your strings are all fixed, as in your example, then all you need is to manually count the length of the strings, determine the longest per column, and use a fixed width:

```
 printf ("%-10s ", someString);
```

where `10` is a placeholder for the actual number.